# Laravel Eloquent - Using array in find() method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables - `users`, `products` and `orders`
There is a relation between `users` and `orders` (`users` has many `orders`).

`orders` table contains `product_id` and `user_id` column.

Now I want to access the product details of orders for a user.

What I am trying:

```
public function myOrders(){
    $orders = Auth::user()->orders->pluck('product_id');
    $products = Product::find($orders);
    return view('shop.myorders', compact('products'));
}
```

But this is not working. Can anyone help me? What other way can be better to achieve this?

Comment: Find is the same as `where('id', '=', ?)->first()`. Use `->get()` and `whereIn()` instead.

Comment: Yup, whereIn() solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, `find()` will always return 1 item, and expects a string/int for the parameter. You want to use `where` and `get` instead. With an array of ids, you can use `whereIn`.

```
public function myOrders(){
    $orders = Auth::user()->orders->pluck('product_id');
    $products = Product::whereIn('id', $orders)->get();
    return view('shop.myorders', compact('products'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks your solution worked. But laravel documentation says that we can use an array as parameter to call find() method to get matching results- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: Ah, I see that they added that in 5.2. I'll have to remember that.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have `orders()` relation defined in the `Product` model:

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class)
}
```

Then you'll be able to load products from all user's orders:

```
$products = Product::whereHas('orders', function($q) {
        $q->where('user_id', auth()->id())
    })->get();
```